# Collection as asset not snappable like objects as assets In blender

Tags: asset-browser

I used blender asset browser today and found a weird thing if you have marked an object as an asset then it has a hitbox around it indicating where it snaps when importing in another file using Asset Browser but this isn't available when you mark a collection as an asset, any fixes? I want to import the collection as is for its freedom of editability but also want snapping features

Comment: Hello. This is a known limitation of the collection as assets. Not much you can do AFAIK